# SQL: How to access values (and ignore duplicates) and group them by their dates

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using C#.NET and NPGSQL to interact with a postgresql database.
At the moment, my table looks somewhat like this:

```
  +----------------------------+
  | worked_hours     dates     |
  +----------------------------+
  | 0             01.08.2015   |
  | 0             01.08.2015   |
  | 0             01.08.2015   |
  | ....          .....        |
  | 3.83                       |
  | 3.83                       |
  | 3.83                       |
  | ....                       |
  | 4.79                       |
  | 4.79          ....         |
  | 4.79          01.08.2015   |
  | ....          ....         |
  +----------------------------+
```

This is just for 1 out of over 30 days.

What I would like to do with the table is to get the sum of the worked_hours for each day

Do you have any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Your table has 2 columns? Please show some code for what you've tried so far.

Comment: It has 6 though the other ones aren't relevant to what I'm trying to achieve here. I also haven't tried much to solve this problem so far since I have no clue how I would go about that. I'm fairly new to programming and started dealing with databases/tables and sql 2 days ago

Comment: Can you state exactly what you want to achieve, as your question is a bit confusing right now. Are you just trying to sum the hours worked for a given day? Else this is going to turn out to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'm trying my best to make myself clear but I hardly know what I am doing as you can surely tell.  I want to return the worked hours of every single day, separately.

Comment: OK so the sum of the worked_hours column, per day then. Your question says something rather different, so perhaps you could re-word it to make it clear. Your should have your answer in the most recent one posted.

Comment: Showing patches of identical `worked_hours` seems to be a misleading example. Or there is something else to consider, you did not explain yet? Are those supposed to be the duplicates to ignore? Typically you would have more columns to identify "duplicates". The same duration is a pretty error-prone indicator for a "duplicate" ... Start by explaining *exactly* how duplicates can be identified.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to presume that all values are the same for each day.  Perhaps that is not a reasonable assumption.

You need to get the distinct values and then sum them.  Here is one method in Postgres:

```
select sum(worked_hours)
from (select distinct on (date) t.*
      from table t
      order by date
     ) t;
```

Another method might be to sum the averages for each day:

```
select sum(avgwh)
from (select date, avg(worked_hours) as avgwh
      from table t
      group by date
     ) t;
```

Comment: I should've clarified that what I was showed you was just an example. Every day has different values, I was just trying to demonstrate the structure

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY column_name` after your `SELECT`

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... , columnN 
FROM table1
GROUP BY column2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(worked_hours), dates 
from table 
group by dates
```

Comment: This is giving me a syntax error at "dates" at the end of the line. I forgot to mention it by my dates column also contains the time. Could that be why?

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like below - replace the table name.

```
          select sum(worked_hours), CONVERT(VARCHAR,dates,101) AS [DateAdded] 
           from TableName GROUP by CONVERT(VARCHAR,dates,101)
```